# How to write this piecewise fucntion in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

[Function f(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2C74.png)

[Function S(t;n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE7I6.png)

I am writing a program for different value of n, t & T.

**My Attempt:**

```
import math
def S(t, n, T):
    i=1
    res=complex(0,0)
    while i<=n:
        x=(complex(1,0)/complex(-1,2))
        y=((complex(2,0)*complex(-1,2)*complex(math.pi,0)*complex(t,0))/complex(T,0)).real
        res+=x* complex(math.sinh(y),0)
        i+=1
    res*=4/math.pi
    return res
```

You can use value of of n=1, t=2(pi)(0.01) and T=2(pi)

I know that this code might contain errors but I, actually, want to know that how to write this function S(t;n) in python 2.7. Is making all of them in complex form an accurate way? I highly doubt this. Just give me a hint. I am new to this community. Sorry for any problems. Thank you!

Comment: If it helps you, you can write complex numbers in python in a manner similar to mathematics. `complex(4, 6) == 4 + 6j`

Comment: Unless I am mistaking something, x is constant and should be moved before while loop

Comment: ...why on earth complex....this is a simple real Fourier series. the`i` is the summation index!

Comment: Additionally, please indicate whether your code does not work as expected and what happens when you run it

Comment: ...and BTW the Sn(t)-> f(t) is point-wise convergence.

Comment: This was a dumb question. @mikuszefski yes, `i` is the summation index! I took it as complex. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

...not sure why I bother... but:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def s_n(t, T, n):
    valList=[1./( 2 * i - 1 ) * np.sin( 2 * (2 * i - 1) *np.pi * t / T)  for i in range(1,n)]
    return sum(valList)


fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax=fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

tList = np.linspace(-1,4,75)
y1List = np.fromiter( ( s_n(t,3,2) for t in tList ), np.float )
y15List = np.fromiter( ( s_n(t,3,15) for t in tList ), np.float )

ax.plot(tList, y1List)
ax.plot(tList, y15List)

plt.show()
```

[image: Fourier]

....nothing complex.